# Running emulator aosp_arm64 after downloading the source on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, android

I am am trying to run the emulator for aosp_source code : arm64 target. 
I have downloaded the source code from the android AOSP master , and built the android image.

Every time I try to start the emulator it hangs with android logo screen. It never boots to the home screen.

I followed the below steps to build the source code:

1. => source build/envsetup.sh
2. => lunch aosp_arm64-eng
3. => make -j24
4. => emulator

List of devices attached
adb server version (40) doesn't match this client (39); killing...
* daemon started successfully *
emulator-5554   device

I can even see that emulator in the adb devices list on my host  but the emulator screen just pops up with the "android" logo . It never boots to home menu even after a long time
I tried running  with "emulator -verbose" but i only get these debug logs :

```
emulator: Starting QEMU main loop                                                                                                  
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service    
...
VERBOSE: AdbHostServer.cpp:49: Send [0012host:emulator:5555] to adb daemon.
emulator: WARNING: Ignoring invalid http proxy: Bad format: invalid port number (must be decimal)
VERBOSE: AdbHostServer.cpp:49: Send [0012host:emulator:5555] to adb daemon.
emulator: onGuestSendCommand: [0x5313d60] Adb connected, start proxing data
emulator: 'magic' skin format detected: 480x800
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get the latest version, skipping check (current version '28.0.15-5109391')
```

Any help is appreciated to start the  emulator for arm?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error after following steps:

1. down AOSP android 9.0.0_r9
2. lunch aosp_arm64-eng
3. make -j8
4. emulator

> List of devices attached adb server version (40) doesn't match this client (39); killing... * daemon started successfully * emulator-5554 device

for this problem, I sovled it by use the aosp/out/host/linux-x86/bin/adb instead of other adb;

for the "android" logo interface, after

```
adb shell
logcat -v threadtime -b all
```

it shows that the surfaceflinger crashes repeatly, I do not know why.

```
07-04 12:41:26.016  2288  2288 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
07-04 12:41:26.018  2288  2288 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
07-04 12:41:26.018  2288  2288 F DEBUG   : pid: 2140, tid: 2140, name: surfaceflinger  >>> /system/bin/surfaceflinger  con
st&, std::__1::function const&)>)+968)
07-04 12:41:26.151  2288  2288 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 00000000000340c4  /system/lib64/android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.1.so (android::hardware::graphics::composer::V2_1::BpHwComposer
Client::executeCommands(unsigned int, android::hardware::hidl_vec const&, std::__1::function const&)>)+160)
07-04 12:41:26.151  2288  2288 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 000000000006bbc4  /system/lib64/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::Hwc2::impl::Composer::execute()+1576)
07-04 12:41:26.151  2288  2288 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 000000000006d93c  /system/lib64/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::Hwc2::impl::Composer::validateDisplay(unsigned long, unsigned int*, u
nsigned int*)+240)
07-04 12:41:26.152  2288  2288 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 000000000007733c  /system/lib64/libsurfaceflinger.so (HWC2::Display::validate(unsigned int*, unsigned int*)+68)
07-04 12:41:26.152  2288  2288 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 000000000007d1ec  /system/lib64/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::HWComposer::prepare(android::DisplayDevice&)+220)
07-04 12:41:26.152  2288  2288 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 0000000000068ea8  /system/lib64/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::DisplayDevice::prepareFrame(android::HWComposer&)+32)
07-04 12:41:26.152  2288  2288 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 00000000000a7ed4  /system/lib64/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::SurfaceFlinger::handleMessageRefresh()+1548)
07-04 12:41:26.153  2288  2288 F DEBUG   :     #10 pc 00000000000a7824  /system/lib64/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::SurfaceFlinger::onMessageReceived(int)+3832)
07-04 12:41:26.153  2288  2288 F DEBUG   :     #11 pc 0000000000013fbc  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+336)
07-04 12:41:26.153  2288  2288 F DEBUG   :     #12 pc 0000000000013dd0  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+60)
07-04 12:41:26.153  2288  2288 F DEBUG   :     #13 pc 0000000000097f8c  /system/lib64/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::impl::MessageQueue::waitMessage()+84)
07-04 12:41:26.154  2288  2288 F DEBUG   :     #14 pc 00000000000a6040  /system/lib64/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::SurfaceFlinger::run()+20)
07-04 12:41:26.154  2288  2288 F DEBUG   :     #15 pc 00000000000031ac  /system/bin/surfaceflinger (main+936)
07-04 12:41:26.154  2288  2288 F DEBUG   :     #16 pc 00000000000aca4c  /system/lib64/libc.so (__libc_init+88)
```

after use stack to dump the detail info, it shows:

```
Revision: '0'
pid: 2140, tid: 2140, name: surfaceflinger  >>> /system/bin/surfaceflinger   memcpy(void*, void const* pass_object_size0, unsigned long)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                bionic/libc/include/bits/fortify/string.h:51
  v-------------->  android::hardware::MessageQueue::MemTransaction::copyFrom(unsigned int*, unsigned long, unsigned long)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       system/libfmq/include/fmq/MessageQueue.h:533
  v-------------->  android::hardware::MessageQueue::read(unsigned int*, unsigned long)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          system/libfmq/include/fmq/MessageQueue.h:1061
  v-------------->  android::hardware::graphics::composer::V2_1::CommandReaderBase::readQueue(unsigned int, android::hardware::hidl_vec const&)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                hardware/interfaces/graphics/composer/2.1/utils/command-buffer/include/composer-command-buffer/2.1/ComposerCommandBuffer.h:600
  v-------------->  operator() >                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           frameworks/native/services/surfaceflinger/DisplayHardware/ComposerHal.cpp:844
  v-------------->  _ZNSt3__18__invokeIRZN7android4Hwc24impl8Composer7executeEvE4$_15JNS1_8hardware8graphics8composer4V2_15ErrorEbjRKNS7_8hidl_vecINS7_11hidl_handleEEEEEEDTclclsr3std3__1E7forwardIT_Efp_Espclsr3std3__1E7forwardIT0_Efp0_EEEOSH_DpOSI_                                                                                                                                                                                                                       external/libcxx/include/type_traits:4480
  v-------------->  void std::__1::__invoke_void_return_wrapper::__call const&>(android::Hwc2::impl::Composer::execute()::$_15&, android::hardware::graphics::composer::V2_1::Error&&, bool&&, unsigned int&&, android::hardware::hidl_vec const&)  external/libcxx/include/__functional_base:349
  0000000000072210  _ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7android4Hwc24impl8Composer7executeEvE4$_15NS_9allocatorIS6_EEFvNS2_8hardware8graphics8composer4V2_15ErrorEbjRKNS9_8hidl_vecINS9_11hidl_handleEEEEEclEOSD_ObOjSI_$7a826238dad3ebd41529eab7fba29d7b+428                                                                                                                                                                                                                      external/libcxx/include/functional:1562
  v-------------->  std::__1::function const&)>::operator()(android::hardware::graphics::composer::V2_1::Error, bool, unsigned int, android::hardware::hidl_vec const&) const                                                                                                                        external/libcxx/include/functional:1916
  00000000000331b0  android::hardware::graphics::composer::V2_1::BpHwComposerClient::_hidl_executeCommands(android::hardware::IInterface*, android::hardware::details::HidlInstrumentor*, unsigned int, android::hardware::hidl_vec const&, std::__1::function const&)>)+968                         out/soong/.intermediates/hardware/interfaces/graphics/composer/2.1/android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.1_genc++/gen/android/hardware/graphics/composer/2.1/ComposerClientAll.cpp:1884
  00000000000340c4  android::hardware::graphics::composer::V2_1::BpHwComposerClient::executeCommands(unsigned int, android::hardware::hidl_vec const&, std::__1::function const&)>)+160                                                                                                              out/soong/.intermediates/hardware/interfaces/graphics/composer/2.1/android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.1_genc++/gen/android/hardware/graphics/composer/2.1/ComposerClientAll.cpp:2043
  000000000006bbc4  android::Hwc2::impl::Composer::execute()+1576                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              frameworks/native/services/surfaceflinger/DisplayHardware/ComposerHal.cpp:854
  000000000006d93c  android::Hwc2::impl::Composer::validateDisplay(unsigned long, unsigned int*, unsigned int*)+240                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            frameworks/native/services/surfaceflinger/DisplayHardware/ComposerHal.cpp:605
  000000000007733c  HWC2::Display::validate(unsigned int*, unsigned int*)+68                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   frameworks/native/services/surfaceflinger/DisplayHardware/HWC2.cpp:648
  000000000007d1ec  android::HWComposer::prepare(android::DisplayDevice&)+220                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  frameworks/native/services/surfaceflinger/DisplayHardware/HWComposer.cpp:456
  0000000000068ea8  android::DisplayDevice::prepareFrame(android::HWComposer&)+32                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              frameworks/native/services/surfaceflinger/DisplayDevice.cpp:344
  v-------------->  android::SurfaceFlinger::setUpHWComposer()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 frameworks/native/services/surfaceflinger/SurfaceFlinger.cpp:2072
  00000000000a7ed4  android::SurfaceFlinger::handleMessageRefresh()+1548                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       frameworks/native/services/surfaceflinger/SurfaceFlinger.cpp:1537
  00000000000a7824  android::SurfaceFlinger::onMessageReceived(int)+3832                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       frameworks/native/services/surfaceflinger/SurfaceFlinger.cpp:1508
```